# How to mount volumes with size by ansible?

Tags: ansible

First, do a partition as

```
- name: Create a new partition
  community.general.parted:
    device: /dev/sda1
    number: 3
    state: present
    part_end: 20GiB
    fs_type: xfs
```

Then, mount different volumes with this partition

```
# It should set to 15GB
- name: Mount root
  mount:
    path: /
    src: ...
    fstype: xfs
    state: present

# It should set to 5GB
- name: Mount swap
  mount:
    path: swapfile
    src: ...
    fstype: xfs
    state: present
```

But how to set the `src` value? Since just did a partition for the whole `/dev/sda1`. If set `/dev/sda1` to it maybe the entire space will be given.

On ansible's [mount module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/mount_module.html) document, I didn't find a `size` item to use.

Comment: create two partition.and mount them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On ansible's mount module document, I didn't find a size item to use.

In current context it seems like you made entire disk to one partition.

So It is not possible to specify size during mount, you have to create partition size of your interest while creating partition itself for separate swap, and other partitions.

If you're looking for other options then you can use `opts:`    in mount module.

Comment: By the way, I ran the create partition task got this error: `fatal: [amazonlinux]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable parted in paths: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin"}`. It's running on amazon linux. Do you know why?